# Win 10 UAP - Drawing a Line to the Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm playing around with the Win 10 UAP and trying to draw a Line to the Canvas in C# using the below code but doesn't work.

```
var line = new Line();
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSteelBlue);
line.StrokeThickness = 3;
line.Width = 50;

line.X1 = 0;
line.Y1 = 0;
line.X2 = 50;
line.Y2 = 0;

Canvas.SetTop(line, 50);
Canvas.SetLeft(line, 50);
TheCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

Can someone please point me in the direction where I have gone wrong?

Many thanks,
Tarran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment this line works fine:

```
        var line = new Line();
        line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        line.StrokeThickness = 3;
        //line.Width = 50;
        line.X1 = 0;
        line.Y1 = 0;
        line.X2 = 50;
        line.Y2 = 0;

        Canvas.SetTop(line, 50);
        Canvas.SetLeft(line, 50);


        TheCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```